# Google Drive files not showing in Gmail search results

Tags: gmail, google-drive, gmail-search

Since today, I don't know why because I didn't change anything, if I search for something in Gmail I only get emails as the search results, my Google Drive files are not showing in the search results, any idea why?

Comment: If I search for something in Gmail it has only ever searched my emails?! Have you perhaps been part of this experimental "field trial"? https://www.google.com/experimental/gmailfieldtrial/

Comment: @w3d found it! is a Labs feature, I don't know why, suddenly, it was disabled, I turn it on again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a Labs feature:

[image]

I don't know why it was turned off...