# Re-enable Google Drive results for Gmail searches in Google Apps for Business

Tags: gmail, google-drive, google-workspace-for-business

Google Drive documents results used to be shown below Gmail search results.  That option was a labs enabled tool where when you searched Gmail you would see matching Google Drive documents below the email results.  Is there a way to re-enable that? It appears Google has disabled that function.

This is a "Google Apps for Business" account.

"Apps Search" does not appear under Labs in Settings for any users even though it is enabled in Domain Admin > Apps > Google Apps > Settings for Gmail > Labs

Comment: I still see Google Drive search results when searching in Gmail. Which browser is this?

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention this is on a corporate Google account, Apps for Business...   Same results in multiple browsers and OSs

Comment: I just tested on my university Google account and I experienced the same thing you did. I could not find Drive results. Perhaps this is a limitation of these types of accounts.

Comment: No the results for Google Drive were definitely there just a month ago, something has changed on Google's end.  I'm looking for anyone with insider info who can tell me if there is a way to re-enable those returned results.  Having to login to Google Drive in a separate browser tab is much less convenient.

Comment: Not sure if Business accounts have Labs but it is a Labs feature: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/74946/google-drive-files-not-showing-in-gmail-search-results Perhaps it got disabled as occurred with this person.

Comment: "Apps Search" does not appear under Labs in Settings for any users even though it is enabled in Domain Admin > Apps > Google Apps > Settings for Gmail > Labs

Comment: I don't have it either, I searched online and it is no longer a Labs feature. It is supposed to be integrated with the search. Are there any other settings in Admin or anywhere related to search?

Answer (score 4):

Google is releasing a new "integrated search experience", which allows you to search Gmail, Google Calendar, Google Groups and Google Drive all from the search bar. It's working for me now, and is very similar to the old "Apps Search" lab.

However, it looks like it may only be rolled out to G Suite customers ("G Suite" was formerly known as "Google Apps for Work").

Here is the announcement:

https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2016/10/integrated-search-now-available-in-gmail-drive-groups-calendar.html

Answer (score 3):

There used to be a lab called "Apps Search" for that which was removed by Google and replaced with their own "native" implementation.

The problem is the new native implementation is not available for Google Apps customers as of now, [they promise it early 2016](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com.au/2014/12/upcoming-removal-of-apps-search-lab.html), so we just need to wait.

Comment: It's May 29, and this feature is still not enabled for Google Apps customers :(

Comment: Now it's August 18th, it's officially not early 2016 anymore.