# Google Drive files not showing in Gmail search results (Apps search feature disappeared)

Tags: gmail, google-drive, gmail-search

Some months ago I came here because when I searched for something in Gmail I only got email messages as the search results; my Google Drive files were not showing in the search results. I found out that the labs feature was disabled (never knew why).

[image: Apps search in available labs]

Now I have the same problem, but the thing is that this labs feature, "Apps Search" has disappeared!

Any ideas?

[image: list of enabled labs]

Comment: This was my previous post: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/74946/google-drive-files-not-showing-in-gmail-search-results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [official Gmail Blog](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.ca/2014/12/upcoming-removal-of-apps-search-lab.html)

> We’ll be implementing the instant results feature for Google Apps
>   customers in late-2015 or early 2016*. With this improved experience
>   on the horizon, we’ll be ending the Apps Search lab experiment, which
>   is unstable and provides lower quality results. It will be removed
>   from Gmail Labs and the Advanced Labs Management section in Admin
>   console in early 2015. We will provide additional guidance on the
>   specific date of the lab experiment removal, and the launch of the
>   instant results feature, on the Google Apps Release calendar.

Answer (score 3):

*Labs* are experiments that sometimes graduate and become part of the main project, and sometimes don't. This would appear to be one of the latter.

When a Lab is removed there's generally no announcement about it, it simply stops working. Why? I don't know. Probably because not many people were using it.